# How to jump out of a table with "TAB" key in Qt?

Tags: qt, tabs

I create a window like this. When we press "Tab" key, it runs from BT1->Table->BT2. The problem is, in the table, I need to mark the checkboxes with "SPACE" key. And once I jump into the table, when I press "TAB", I can not jump into BT2 any more, but it runs around inside the table. Is there any way to jump out of the table with "TAB" key?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your UI designer just select your tablewidget / tableview and uncheck the tabkeynavigation.

Or from code :

> yourtableview->setTabKeyNavigation(false)